# Homotopy equivalence between a holomorphic vector bundle and the base space

Tags: differential-geometry, homotopy-theory, complex-geometry

Given a smooth manifold $X$, there is a smooth homotopy equivalence between any smooth vector bundle $\pi: E\rightarrow X$ and $X$. It is usually proven by showing that the projection $\pi$ is a so-called smooth *deformation retraction* of $E$ on $X$. Is there a homotopy equivalence between a holomorphic vector bundle $p:F\rightarrow X$ on a complex manifold $X$ and the base space $X$? Is the canonical holomorphic projection $p$ of $F$ onto the complex manifold $X$ a *holomorphic deformation retraction*? Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by a holomorphic deformation retraction? The 0 section of $E \xrightarrow{p} X$ is still, of course, a homotopy inverse to $p$. This homotopy can be taken to be smooth, but it doesn't make sense to ask if it's holomorphic since the unit interval isn't a complex manifold.

Comment: You are right. It does not make sense to talk about holomorphic homotopy. That is why I am asking if there is a version of the definition which makes sense. However, even if there is no holomorphic homotopy between $p$ and $0$ I still believe that one should be able to construct a holomorphic homotopy operator such that $\pi^*\circ0^*$ is chain homotopic to the identity on $E$. I believe that the hypercohomology of the holomorphic differential forms on the total space of $E$ and that of $X$ are isomorphic.

Comment: Ah I understand. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: In holomorphic setting one usually requires a smooth homotopy $f_t$ such that each $f_t$ is holomorphic. I know this in the context of "holomorphic contractibility."